# Split a column by element and create new ones with pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

**Goal:** I want to split one single column by elements (not the strings cells) and, from that division, create new columns, where the element is the title of the new column and the other values from another columns compose the respective column.

There is a way of doing that with pandas? Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
[IN]:
A    1
A    2
A    6
A   99
B    7
B    8
B   19
B   18

[OUT]:

A   B
1   7
2   8
6  19
99 18
```

Comment: There are 2 columns of data or one column of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an alternative if 2 column input data:

```
print(df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     6
3    A    99
4    B     7
5    B     8
6    B    19
7    B    18
```

---

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).to_dict())
print(df1)

    A   B
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   6  19
3  99  18
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
      col
0  A    1
1  A    2
2  A    6
3  A   99
4  B    7
5  B    8
6  B   19
7  B   18
```

---

```
df1 = df['col'].str.split(expand=True)
g = df1.groupby(0).cumcount()

df2 = df1.set_index([0, g])[1].unstack(0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df2)
    A   B
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   6  19
3  99  18
```

If 2 columns input data:

```
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     6
3    A    99
4    B     7
5    B     8
6    B    19
7    B    18

g = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
df2 = df.set_index(['col1', g])['col2'].unstack(0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df2)

    A   B
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   6  19
3  99  18
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I keep getting this error: KeyError: 'col1'

Comment: @BrunoSantos - It is column name with values, change it by your data. What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: You're right. print (df.columns) gives "[u'col1', u'col2']". Thanks again.